# Audio composition using Windows Phone 8.1 media editing APIs

Tags: c#, audio, windows-runtime, media, windows-phone-8.1

I want to join multiple AAC audio files which are audio recording in real in a Windows Phone 8.1 app. Actually I want pause/resume feature in audio recording. In MP3 encoding I can simply join the buffer to have composition of audio files but in case of AAC it's not working. MP3 encoding profile is not available in Windows Phone 8.1. I thought `MediaComposition` will help me to stitch the audio recording, but I am getting exceptions it it.

I tried first to create `MediaClip` object from audio file but I am getting `ArgumentException` with message `Source can not be audio file`. Then I tried to create `BackgroundAudioTrack` object from audio file & added in `MediaComposition`. Then I tried to set source to `MediaElement` with these methods `cvMediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(comp.GenerateMediaStreamSource());` and `cvMediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(comp.GeneratePreviewMediaStreamSource(100, 100));`, both throws `ArgumentException` with message `The parameter is incorrect.` Any one here to point me out to correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but figured I would answer for you and others in case it is found during search.

As you noticed, audio clips are not supported directly in MediaComposition in Windows Phone 8.1. This has been fixed for Windows 10 (and MediaComposition itself is now part of the Universal Windows Platform so you can use it on many platforms).

For Windows Phone 8.1, the issue is likely tied to the fact that BackgroundAudioTracks don't dictate the length of "content" (per se) of the composition. To do this, you will likely need to add a blank MediaClip first. You can create a MediaClip from the color black for instance (MediaClip.CreateFromColor) and have it be as long as the total length of the background audio tracks. That should then let it work as expected on Windows Phone 8.1.

If you continue to run into any of these issues if you give it a whirl on Windows 10, please let me know and I can get some bugs filed :).